# C# Fuel Station, If a certain amount of litres are entered (10) then the price of the car wash goes to $5 from $9

Tags: c#, int

C# Fuel Station, If a certain amount of litres are entered (10) then the price of the car wash goes to $5 from $9
Here is my that segment of code 
There aren't any mistakes (apparently) but when i run it and select button "Yes" to the car wash, it runs into an error, since its a fuel station it needs to be totaled in the end so it must be int and quite frankly i'm completely stuck

```
    private void btnCarWashYes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Litres = Convert.ToInt16(txtTotalLitresDisplay);
        if (Litres > 9)
        {
           lblCarWashDisplay.Text = "$5.00";
        }
        else
        {
           lblCarWashDisplay.Text = "$9.00";
        }           
    }
    private void btnCarWashNo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblCarWashDisplay.Text = "$0.00";
    }
```

to select the amount of fuel you press buttons with numbers, heres that code if its necessary

```
private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Output += 1;
            txtTotalLitresDisplay.Text = Output;
        }
```

Please help, thankyou

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix the call to Convert.ToInt16, it needs to use txtTotalLitresDisplay.Text

Answer (score 0):

```
Litres = Convert.ToInt16(txtTotalLitresDisplay);
```

should be

```
Litres = Convert.ToInt16(txtTotalLitresDisplay.Text);
```

You're trying to pass in a TextBox control to the `Convert.ToInt16` method instead of a string.

Comment: No problem, easy mistake to make.